# A variable b showing the following value of each given value in variable a

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

I have a list of values (as series) that looks like this:

```
    a
  12.34
  13.15
  14.36
  15.8
  16.41
```

I would like to create a new variable (b) that holds the following value of each given value. So the output would look like this:

```
    a        b
  12.34    13.15
  13.15    14.36
  14.36    15.8
  15.8     16.41
  16.41     nan
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: `df['b'] = df['a'].shift(-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df['b']=df.shift(-1, axis = 0) 
df
```

When we print Dataframe value it will be as follows:

```
     a        b
0   12.34   13.15
1   13.15   14.36
2   14.36   15.80
3   15.80   16.41
4   16.41   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df["b"] = df["a"].diff(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the entire code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a=pd.Series((12.34,13.15,14.36,15.8,16.41))
b=[]
for x in range(len(a)):
    if x!=len(a)-1:
        b.append(a[x+1])
    else:
        b.append(np.nan)
b=pd.Series(b)
print(b)
```

This would create a new series called b. If u want both a and b in the same dataframe, u can concatenate them.